# Regex in Perl Uninitialized $1

Tags: regex, perl

My string looks like this:

```
<File `../Path/To/My_File.gif'>
```

I want to extract just "Path/To/My_File.gif".

Here is the check I have:

```
if ($row =~ /(?<=File `..\/).*(?=')/) {
      print "Found it!\n";
      print "$1\n";
}
```

I see "Found it!" printed to the console but also get an error saying that $1 is uninitialized. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$1` is the value captured by the first capture (`()`), but you have no captures in your pattern. Fix:

```
/(?<=File `..\/)(.*)(?=')/
```

Simplified:

```
m{File `../(.*)'}
```

More robust:

```
m{File `../([^']*)'}
```